# Have page numbers in base 2?

Tags: google-docs

I would prefer to have the page numbers on each page in binary, instead of decimal. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Is this just for novelty, or is there an actual purpose behind it?

Comment: just for novelty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. Automatic page numbers can only be in base 10.